# Run a string through PHP?

Tags: php, macos, swift, cocoa

How would I go about processing a string through the system PHP?

I've tried doing so with firing up an `NSTask` and feeding arguments to `/usr/bin/php` but I get the results of the PHP CLI, which isn't quite the same thing — for one, the line breaks aren't quite right.

What I'd like is to take a `String`, run it through PHP, and store the result in another `String`. Kind of like a webserver.

Is that possible?

---

**Update** I have tried both the `-f` and `-r` options of the PHP CLI, neither one of them gives me the output I’m looking for.

I suspect that the PHP CLI is not the correct approach here.

I would like to be able to turn a string containing PHP code into a string containing exactly how that code would be parsed by a web server with PHP support.